# Can I create a Snackbar in a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

Possible duplicate: [How to add Snackbars in a BroadcastReceiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428437/how-to-add-snackbars-in-a-broadcastreceiver)

I have this code:

```
BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Snackbar.make(root, "Your RegID is: " + ownerPref.getString("reg_id"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Reference.NewMember));
```

I know the broadcast is being sent and received properly, I checked that with breakpoints. For some reason, though, the Snackbar itself is not being displayed. It works if I call Snackbar.make() outside of the receiver. There's no error in the LogCat either. Help, please!

P.S. I'm using the design support library snackbar, not the default 5.0+ one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Snackbars in a BroadcastReceiver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428437/how-to-add-snackbars-in-a-broadcastreceiver)